# C++ operator = for arrays with class member function

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, c++98

I have a wrapper data structure that I'd like to write a method for the copy assignment operator. I'd really like to do this (because my `byte_array` can do some really cool stuff):

```
byte_array bytes = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF};
```

and the function I'm trying to write looks like this so far:

```
template <int N>
byte_array& byte_array::operator = (const unsigned char (&a)[N]) {
    if(N <= capacity) { //capacity is a class field
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) array[i] = a[i]; //array is a class field
        usage = N; //usage is a class field
    }
    return *this;
}
```

However, this code doesn't compile, as it does not like that I gave it a list. It doesn't like a lot of things about this.

Is there something wrong with the function I wrote, such as the assignment operator only working on objects of the same type (like a conflict of `byte_array` and `unsigned char[]`)? Is it an issue of my 'list' that I'm trying to assign it to not matching up with the `unsigned char[]` type?

I was basing my function off of an answer to [this past question about arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810672#4810672).

Comment: maybe use the type const std::initializer_list<unsigned char>& instead of an array type as  {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF} is not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with

```
byte_array bytes = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF};
```

is that you you do not actually have an array on the right hand side.  You have an *initializer list*, which doesn't have a type.

What you can do though is take a `std::initializer_list<unsigned char>` and that can be constructed from the *initializer list*.

In C++98 you can create a temporary array and then use that array from the assignemnt like

```
byte_array bytes;
//some code
{
    unsigned char temp[] = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF};
    bytes = temp;
}
// more code
```

---

Also note that `Type name = initializer;` is never assignment.  It is called *copy initialization*/*copy list initialization*(if `initializer` is a *initializer list*), and calls the copy/move constructor of the object.  The assignment operator is only ever called then you have an already constructed object.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/ says that `std::initializer_list` is something that was introduced in c++11; however, I must deal with c++98...

Comment: @Peri461 OK.  I added the C++98 tag to your question so that we know as the C++ tag currently means C++14.  AFAIK, this is not possible in C++98.  You would have to create an array and then use that array for the assignment.

Comment: Yikes. Glad to know it's not possible, at least. Thanks. I apologize for not specifying the C++ version ahead of time.

Comment: @Peri461 If you want to do *really cool stuff*, then, I'm afraid, you better use C++11. Otherwise, it's too painful to do cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are trying to assign an initializer_list {a, b, c} and not an array. You might want to take an initializer list as the parameter instead:

```
#include <iostream>


struct byte_array
{
    byte_array& operator = (const std::initializer_list<unsigned char>& tab) {
        for (unsigned char item: tab)
            std::cout << item << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
  byte_array bytes;
  bytes = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
  (void)bytes;
}
```

run it here: http://cpp.sh/2vv6m